# Determining a Missing Data Value in Weighted Average

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

When dealing with weighted averages, how do you solve for X?

$$
\frac{(  84X) + (40*16)}{100} = 10.5 .
$$

Comment: This is just a linear equation in $X$. You remember your algebra and perform the same operations on each side of the equation toward the goal of isolating $X = ...$. I edited your question to format the mathematics - that might help you. If you're really stuck and need to do this just once, try guess-and-check. When you're done, answer your own question (that's allowed on this site).

Comment: @EthanBolker Sadly I've forgotten far too much of my algebra to figure it out that way, and Google hasn't been much help in that regard ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

1. Remove the fraction by multiplying both sides by $100$.
2. Isolate the $X$ term by subtracting the $(40*16)$ from both sides.
3. Remove the coefficient of $X$ by dividing both sides by $84$.

Comment: Thank you for jogging my long-dormant High School math memory with step 3 :)

Comment: @ChayaCooper Lol, no problem mate ;)

Comment: I'm curious what I'm doing wrong that I'm ending up with 4.88 instead of 5?

Comment: @ChayaCooper And as written, that should be the correct answer.  I'm not sure how one would be getting $5$ as an answer.